# Upgrading from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 on debian 6.0.8

Tags: debian, upgrade

How can i upgrade PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.5 on debian 6.0.8 ?

I can't find any documentation on it.

Thanks

Comment: Why you need php 5.5?

Comment: For performances and cache system.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer using Debian stable in that case?